# How can I drop a column from multiple dataframes stored in a list?

Tags: python, pandas

Apologies as I'm new to all this.

I'm playing around with pandas at the moment. I want to drop one particular column across two dataframes stored within a list. This is what I've written.

```
combine = [train, test]

for dataset in combine:
    dataset = dataset.drop('Id', axis=1)
```

However, this doesn't work. If I do this explicitly, such as `train = train.drop('Id', axis=1)`, this works fine.

I appreciate in this case it's two lines either way, but is there some way I can use the list of dataframes to drop the column from both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your solution didn't work is because `dataset` is a name that points to the item in the list `combine`.  You had the right idea to reassign it with `dataset = dataset.drop('Id', axis=1)` but all you did was overwrite the name `dataset` and not really place a new dataframe in the list `combine`

---

**Option 1**

Create a new list

```
combine = [d.drop('Id', axis=1) for d in combine]
```

---

**Option 2**
Or alter each dataframe in place with `inplace=True`

```
for d in combine:
    d.drop('Id', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: That was really quick

Comment: Welp, there goes my option 2.

Comment: Sorry guys.  I'll play nicer, I swear.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much. I'd forgotten about inplace, and had no idea Option 1 was even possible in that format, though it makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe

```
combine = [df1, df2]
for i in range(len(combine)):
    combine[i]=combine[i].drop('Id', axis=1)
```

Comment: I like this approach as it makes a lot more sense to me. However, it's made me wonder if I have my understanding of how DataFrames and lists work together wrong, as I have to call combine[0] or [1] to view the dataframe with the dropped Id field. If I simply call my original train DataFrame, it still displays. Does the list make separate objects, rather than referencing to the given DataFrames?

I'll go research separately, definitely my misunderstanding. Thanks all!

Comment: @Staticwolf you can assign it back , train=combine[0],test=combine[1]